# Index/Match closest Temp value

Tags: excel, date

I have 6 different data loggers, each one with its Date Column (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm), Temp, and Humidity. I have times & dates when some parts were made but I need to figure out which data logger has the closest match by extracting the individual information from each and then highlighting the closest match. This is because the data loggers log the temp & humidity in intervals of 15 minutes, but some parts' manufacturing dates fall between those intervals, that is why I have to get the closest match either up or down.

What I'm struggling with is extracting these temp & humidity values. Some dataloggers start in 2021, and some others in 2018. The "global formula" I have for all the cells is showing me a value when it shouldn't. I've tried with INDEX MATCH, XLOOKUP, and nowhere near what I need.

[image: Example]
|I|J|K|
|-|-|-|
||421-0415-0420||
|Date Time|Temp (F)|Hum (%RH)|
|44551.3083333333|73.4|12.18|
|44551.31875|72.5|9.34|
|44551.3291666667|71.8|8.68|
|44551.3395833333|71.7|8.6|
|44551.35|71.6|8.46|
|44551.3604166667|71.5|8.52|
|44551.3708333333|71.3|8.66|
|44551.38125|71.2|8.8|

Also, the date & times I have to look up are split, on one cell (mm/dd/yyyy) and the other (hh:mm am/pm) and I'm adding them by A#+B# in the formulas as shown below:

These are the values I'm using, but it is showing me a number, which it shouldn't.

[image]

Formula 1: `=INDEX(J3:J33895,MATCH(MIN(ABS(I3:I33895-(Y3+Y4))),ABS(I3:I33895-(Y3+Y4)),0))`

Formula 2: `=XLOOKUP($Y3+$Y4,I3:I33895,Data!$J$3:$J$33895,"-",1)`

Formula 3: `=XLOOKUP(0,ABS(I3:I33895-(Y3+Y4)),J3:J33895,,1)`

I have almost 10,000 lines where the formulas go, that is why I need a global formula that if the year is not found just leaves it blank, but if a value is found pretty close, then shows it correctly.

Comment: MATCH() has the match_type argument to go above or below, vlookup() equal to or below. So you can double them with an if() and add a defined amount to the original search value if the one found is too far away.

Comment: Can you share a data sample of the 6 data loggers with cells reference? Also in a table and not as image, please. As i understand you need to syncronize the data, so each row in a dataset is matched with all the others; correct? Do you want strictly a formula based solution or is VBA acceptable?

Comment: Sorry @EvilBlueMonkey I don't know how to add it without being an image. As soon as I copy the table it converts it to an image.

Data tab 
Each data logger has 3 columns, Date/Time, Temp & RH

Main tab
For every row, it looks at the temp & RH value on each data logger.

This tab has the date/time split as shown on the main post.

I would prefer the formula, otherwise, I would have to save it as xlsm instead of xlsx, and per our network security those files are blocked.

Comment: Under your question there are a few labels reporting `Share`, `Edit`, `Follow` and `Flag`. Click on the `Edit` one and you will enter the edit window of your answer. Right over the body of text that is your answer and the label `Answer` there is a menu with several text editing options. On the right side of that menu there is a question mark. Click on the question mark. A second menu will appear with more labels. Click on the label `Tables` and you'll have the instructions to create a table.

Comment: You can also use formulas to easily create a table from the data in your Excel sheet. Let's say you want to report the range I1:K11. Let's assume you have nothing past column AZ. Write this formula `=INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)&"|"&I1` in cell BB1 and drag it to cover range BB1:BE10. Then write this formula `=BG1&UNICHAR(10)&BE1` in cell BG2 and drag it to cover range BG2:BG11. Then copy the cell BG11 and paste it as value in another cell. Select the cell, press F2 and copy the whole content of the cell. That's the corpus of the table. You'll need to add the headers and you'll have your table.

Comment: Headers are quite straight foward. You need a first row with the actual headers and a second row of `|-|`. For our example the first row will be `|I|J|K|` and the second row will be `|-|-|-|`.

Comment: The final result should be something like `|I|J|K|_|-|-|-|_||421-0415-0420||_|Date Time|Temp (F)|Hum (%RH)|_|44551.3083333333|73.4|12.18|_|44551.31875|72.5|9.34|_|44551.3291666667|71.8|8.68|_|44551.3395833333|71.7|8.6|_|44551.35|71.6|8.46|_|44551.3604166667|71.5|8.52|_|44551.3708333333|71.3|8.66|_|44551.38125|71.2|8.8|` only that instead of each `_` you should have a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this table (without the headers) into a new sheet:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | AA | AB | AC | AD | AE | AF | AG | AH | AI | AJ | AK | AL | AM | AN | AO | AP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 421-0415-0420 |  |  | 421-0415-0421 |  |  | 421-0415-0422 |  |  | 421-0415-0423 |  |  | 421-0415-0424 |  |  | 421-0415-0425 |  |  |  | SEARCH |  |  |  | Data log ID | =A1 |  |  | =D1 |  |  | =G1 |  |  | =J1 |  |  | =M1 |  |  | =P1 |  |  |
| Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) |  | Date | 44551 |  |  | Min value difference | =ABS(MIN(A:A)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(MIN(D:D)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(MIN(G:G)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(MIN(J:J)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(MIN(M:M)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(MIN(P:P)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  |
| 44551.3083333333 | 73.4 | 12.18 | 44551.3055555556 | 71.3 | 10.49 | 44551.3027777778 | 71.94 | 8.74 | 44551.35 | 72.91 | 12.06 | 44552.7555555556 | 71.47 | 11.02 | 44916.3083333333 | 71.78 | 8.5 |  | Time | 0.308333333333333 |  |  | Low match difference | =ABS(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,A:A,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(D:D,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,D:D,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(G:G,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,G:G,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(J:J,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,J:J,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,M:M,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(P:P,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,P:P,1))-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  |
| 44551.31875 | 72.5 | 9.34 | 44551.3159722222 | 72.33 | 10.61 | 44551.3131944444 | 72.62 | 8.47 | 44551.3604166667 | 72.41 | 9.1 | 44552.7659722222 | 71.9 | 11.63 | 44916.31875 | 72.07 | 12.18 |  | Tolerance | 0.0104166666666667 |  |  | High match difference | =ABS(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,A:A,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(D:D,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,D:D,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(G:G,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,G:G,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(J:J,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,J:J,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,M:M,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(INDEX(P:P,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,P:P,1)+1)-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  |
| 44551.3291666667 | 71.8 | 8.68 | 44551.3263888889 | 72.57 | 12.1 | 44551.3236111111 | 72.64 | 10.65 | 44551.3708333333 | 73.25 | 10.14 | 44552.7763888889 | 71.8 | 11.68 | 44916.3291666667 | 72.23 | 10.66 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 44551.3395833333 | 71.7 | 8.6 | 44551.3368055555 | 73.37 | 9.13 | 44551.3340277778 | 73.11 | 9.99 | 44551.38125 | 73.27 | 8.66 | 44552.7868055556 | 73.05 | 11.61 | 44916.3395833333 | 72.19 | 9.62 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) |
| 44551.35 | 71.6 | 8.46 | 44551.3472222222 | 71.74 | 10.13 | 44551.3444444444 | 72.42 | 9.34 | 44551.3916666667 | 72.63 | 11.91 | 44552.7972222222 | 72.65 | 8.63 | 44916.35 | 73.08 | 11.4 |  | COSTUM DL |  |  |  | Best match | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,Y2:Y4),Y2:Y4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(A:A),A:A,1,FALSE),INDEX(A:A,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,A:A,1)),INDEX(A:A,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,A:A,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(Y7,A:C,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(Y7,A:C,3,FALSE) | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,AB2:AB4),AB2:AB4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(D:D),D:D,1,FALSE),INDEX(D:D,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,D:D,1)),INDEX(D:D,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,D:D,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(AB7,D:F,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(AB7,D:F,3,FALSE) | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,AE2:AE4),AE2:AE4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(G:G),G:G,1,FALSE),INDEX(G:G,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,G:G,1)),INDEX(G:G,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,G:G,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(AE7,G:I,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(AE7,G:I,3,FALSE) | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,AH2:AH4),AH2:AH4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(J:J),J:J,1,FALSE),INDEX(J:J,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,J:J,1)),INDEX(J:J,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,J:J,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(AH7,J:L,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(AH7,J:L,3,FALSE) | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,AK2:AK4),AK2:AK4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(M:M),M:M,1,FALSE),INDEX(M:M,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,M:M,1)),INDEX(M:M,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,M:M,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(AK7,M:O,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(AK7,M:O,3,FALSE) | =CHOOSE(MATCH(AGGREGATE(5,6,AN2:AN4),AN2:AN4,0),VLOOKUP(MIN(P:P),P:P,1,FALSE),INDEX(P:P,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,P:P,1)),INDEX(P:P,MATCH($U$2+$U$3,P:P,1)+1)) | =VLOOKUP(AN7,P:R,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(AN7,P:R,3,FALSE) |
| 44551.3604166667 | 71.5 | 8.52 | 44551.3576388889 | 72.53 | 10.52 | 44551.3548611111 | 72.44 | 11.42 | 44551.4020833333 | 72.02 | 11.11 | 44552.8076388889 | 71.32 | 11.39 | 44916.3604166667 | 72.12 | 10.8 |  | Data log | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 44551.3708333333 | 71.3 | 8.66 | 44551.3680555555 | 72.64 | 11.05 | 44551.3652777778 | 71.54 | 9.16 | 44551.4125 | 72.52 | 11.05 | 44552.8180555555 | 71.56 | 12.07 | 44916.3708333333 | 73.04 | 10.8 |  | Data log ID | =INDEX(Y1:AP1,(U8-1)*3+1) |  |  | Time difference | =ABS(Y7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(AB7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(AE7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(AH7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(AK7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  | =ABS(AN7-($U$2+$U$3)) |  |  |
| 44551.38125 | 71.2 | 8.8 | 44551.3784722222 | 72.73 | 10.33 | 44551.3756944444 | 72.32 | 10.43 | 44551.4229166666 | 72.88 | 10.87 | 44552.8284722222 | 72.68 | 8.95 | 44916.38125 | 72.85 | 8.63 |  | Tolerance filter | =IF(ABS(T13-(U2+U3)>$U$4),"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | Tolerance filter | =IF(Y9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | =IF(AB9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | =IF(AE9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | =IF(AH9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | =IF(AK9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  | =IF(AN9>$U$4,"Exceeding","Acceptable") |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =INDEX(Y7:AP7,(U8-1)*3+1) | =INDEX(Y7:AP7,(U8-1)*3+2) | =INDEX(Y7:AP7,(U8-1)*3+3) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | BEST ACROSS DLs |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Index | =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(Y9:AP9)/(Y9:AP9=MIN(Y9:AP9))/(Y10:AP10="Acceptable"),1)-COLUMN(Y10)+1,"") |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Data log ID | =IF(U17="","",INDEX(Y1:AP1,U17)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Date Time | Temp (F) | Hum (%RH) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(U17="","",INDEX(Y7:AP7,U17)) | =IF(U17="","",INDEX(Y7:AP7,U17+1)) | =IF(U17="","",INDEX(Y7:AP7,U17+2)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

You should obtain this (with some format editing):

[image]

Range A:R contains the data logs.

Range X1:AN10 contains most of the formulas.

Range T1:U4 contains the data of the match to be searched (cells for you to be edited are highlighted in yellow).

Range T7:V13 contains the closest match in the specified data log (you can specify the index of the data log in cell U8). If no match is found (within the tolerance specified in cell U4), it will be reported the closest match for the specified data log with the tolerance filter value reported as "Exceeding".

Range T16:V21 contains the closest match in all data logs. If no match is found (within the tolerance specified in cell U4), no result will be reported.

In order for it to work, each single data logs have to be ordered by `Date Time` columns in ascending order.

Comment: I never thanked you for the time you spent helping me, really appreciate it.

Comment: Your appriciation is appriciated.